# laravel have transactions status?

Tags: php, laravel-5

In **codeigniter** we have command `trans_status()` that check transaction is successful or not:

```
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    // error woun't be generated...
}
```

i want to know `laravel 5.*` have any like that?

Comment: Wrapping it in a `try` - `catch` would probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can get transaction status in laravel like this. [Laravel Manual for `DB::transaction`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions)

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function transactionalQuery()
{
    try {
        DB::transaction(function ($data) {
            // do something
        });
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Reference Code](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-know-transaction-status?page=1)

**Author Name:** JarekTkaczyk